# How do I expand a macro into a tabular head?

Tags: tables, macros

I would like to be able to define a macro that can be used in the tabular definition. How can I do this?

This does not work:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\gdef\buildtabularhead{|||}

\begin{tabular}{\buildtabularhead}
1 & 2 &3\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is probably not practical but it's a nice demonstration of `\expandafter` and gets around the problem of macros in the table preamble with the `array` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\def\buildtabularhead{|c|c|c|}
\expandafter\tabular\expandafter{\buildtabularhead}
1 & 2 &3\\
\endtabular
\end{document}
```

The two `\expandafter`s make sure that the macro `\buildtabularhead` is expanded *before* LaTeX knows it should be expecting a `tabular` preamble.  Notice also that instead of `\begin{tabular}`...`\end{tabular}` I had to use `\tabular`...`\endtabular`.  Internally the former does the same as the latter but surrounding it with a group and doing important checks, including proper nesting (See source2e Section 54.1).

Answer (score 19):

Better define it as a new column type using the `array` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{L}{|l|l|l|}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{L}
1 & 2 &3\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

I had a very dirty answer, but I found theneater solution below while reading the documentation of the `array` package. In particular, this is inspired from how the `*` column specifier is defined there.

The idea is to introduce the new column type `\expand` (`\newcolumntype` sets up most of the necessary ingredients), and then redefine `\NC@rewrite@\expand` to expand the next token with `\expandafter`, and then continue the action that `array` is doing at that time (namely finding user-defined column types and replacing them by their definition).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\makeatletter
\newcolumntype{\expand}{}
\long\@namedef{NC@rewrite@\string\expand}{\expandafter\NC@find}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\def\mypream{c|*{2}{c|||}}
\begin{tabular}{c\expand\mypream cc}
    a   & b   & d     &e   & f     & apsdoi \\
    cde & def & erasd &arp & sefoi & wp     
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can I use this solution if `\mypream` has a parameter? I tried using `\expand{\mypream{something}}` but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I haven't tested, but I'd expect `\expand\mypream{something}` to work.

Comment: It doesn't. Perhaps I should ask a new question.

Comment: It does.  To test, I just replaced the definition of `\mypream` by `\def\mypream#1{#1|*{2}{#1|||}}` and replaced `c\expand\mypream cc` by `c\expand\mypream{c}cc`, and got the correct tabular.

Comment: Oh. You can add your solution to [my question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/199238).

Comment: @JosephWright has answered in details, and you have given a better way to proceed in your case, so I'll abstain :-).

Answer (score 6):

It does work when you correct your tabular header.

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\buildtabularhead{|c|c|c|}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{\buildtabularhead}
  1 & 2 & 3 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that this solution won't work if you are using the `array` package or any other package that loads it.

Comment: @Alan @Christian I am using the array package! Is their a way to by-pass the issue?

Comment: @salty Yes, use Martin's solution of defining a new column type.  It achieves exactly the same aim but just slightly differently.

Answer (score 5):

The column definition, you are using as an example is invalid. It only specifies lines and no real columns. If you change it to something like `\gdef\buildtabularhead{|c|c|c|}` it works as expected.

Comment: still gives me an error Illegal pream-token

Comment: @saltypen: At Alan Munn pointed out above this doesn't work when the `array` package is loaded (which is loaded by many other tabular related packages ...)

Answer (score 5):

You can use the array package and still be able to specify the column specifiers through a macro as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}


\def\test#1{\newcolumntype{L}{#1}}
\test{clr}

\begin{tabular}{L}
1 & 2 &3\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

This can be useful, if you automating table generation through scripts.

Comment: Good answer (sorry out of votes for today), but `X` is a bad choice because it will collide with the `tabularx` package once loaded.

Comment: @Martin you right edited to `L', thanks.

Comment: @Yiannis: Can you explain why you wrap the `\newcolumntype` in a macro?

Comment: @Hendrik  Essentially because I wanted to pass a parameter. Lamport's original definition allowed  the following
`\newcommand{\X}{clr} \begin{tabular}{\X} . . `. The `array` package takes great care not to expand the preamble. By defining another macro you can make sure that the argument is expanded. In a more realistic application the `\test` macro would be used to set-up the tabular head programmatically. Another approach is to use `expandafter` as Mathew's fine answer demonstrates.

Comment: @Yiannis: I'm not sure if I can follow. Would `\test{\X}` be any different from `\newcolumntype{L}{\X}`?

Comment: @HendrikVogt No, but it is easier to do `\expandafter\test\expandafter{\X}` than `\expandafter\newcolumntype\expandafter{\expandafter L\expandafter}\expandafter{\X}`.  However, perhaps I misunderstood Yiannis.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution with `tblr` environment of [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\NewTblrEnviron{vlinetab}
\SetTblrInner[vlinetab]{vlines}

\begin{document}

\begin{vlinetab}{}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
4 & 5 & 6 \\
7 & 8 & 9 \\
\end{vlinetab}

\end{document}
```

[image]