# Transposing a table with many rows

Tags: tables

I am trying to transpose a table. I have tried the example given in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/83876/153889) and it works. However, when I try more than 5 rows (which when transposed become columns), it throws an error as follows: "Package datatool Error: Can't assign \Gg : there is no key `G` in data base `TransposedTabularDB`." Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{collcell}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{environ}
%\usepackage{showframe}

\def\Midrule{\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]}

\newcounter{CurrentRow}% = column of transposed table
\newcounter{CurrentColumn}
\setcounter{CurrentColumn}{0}
\newtoggle{DoneWithFirstRow}

\newlength{\WidthAdjustment}
\newcommand*{\FirstColumn}[1]{%
    \IfEq{\arabic{CurrentColumn}}{0}{%
        % This is the start of the very first data entry in first row.
        \global\togglefalse{DoneWithFirstRow}%
        \setcounter{CurrentRow}{1}% initial value
    }{%
        % We have already completed a row. Now starting a new row.
        \global\toggletrue{DoneWithFirstRow}%
        \stepcounter{CurrentRow}%
    }%
    \setcounter{CurrentColumn}{0}%
    \NewData{#1}%
}
\newcommand*{\NewData}[1]{%
    \dtlexpandnewvalue%
    \stepcounter{CurrentColumn}%
    \iftoggle{DoneWithFirstRow}{%
        \dtlgetrow{TransposedTabularDB}{\arabic{CurrentColumn}}%
        \dtlappendentrytocurrentrow{\Alph{CurrentRow}}{#1}%
        \dtlrecombine%
    }{%
        \DTLnewrow{TransposedTabularDB}%
        \DTLnewdbentry{TransposedTabularDB}{\Alph{CurrentRow}}{#1}%
    }%
}%

\newcolumntype{F}{>{\collectcell\FirstColumn}c<{\endcollectcell}}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\collectcell\NewData}{c}<{\endcollectcell}}

%% No longer needed since we switched to NewEnviron
%% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12234/how-do-i-expand-a-macro-into-a-tabular-head
%\newcommand{\SaveColumnSpecificationAsZ}[1]{\newcolumntype{Z}{#1}}


\newtoggle{EncounteredDataRow}

\newsavebox{\TempBox}
\DTLnewdb{TransposedTabularDB}

\NewEnviron{Ttabular}[1]{%
    %\SaveColumnSpecificationAsZ{#1}%
    % Initialize in case of multiple uses
    \setcounter{CurrentColumn}{0}%
    \global\togglefalse{EncounteredDataRow}%
    \savebox{\TempBox}{%
        \begin{tabular}{FCCCCCC}% over speced tabular
            \BODY%
        \end{tabular}%
    }%
    \begin{tabular}{#1}\toprule%
    % This could be made smarter to detect number of columns
    \DTLforeach*{TransposedTabularDB}{\Aa=A, \Ba=B, \Ca=C, \Dd=D, \Ee=E, \Ff = F}{%
      \DTLiffirstrow{}{\\\midrule}%    
        \Aa & \Ba & \Ca & \Dd & \Ee & \Ff%
    }\\\bottomrule%
    \end{tabular}%
}%

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{Ttabular}{cccccc}
\bfseries Name & Alice & Bob & Chuck & Dave & Eve\\
\bfseries Sex & Female & Male & Male & Male & Female\\
\bfseries Age & 18 & 19 & 20 & 21 & 22\\
\bfseries Age & 18 & 19 & 20 & 21 & 22\\
\bfseries Age & 18 & 19 & 20 & 21 & 22\\
\bfseries Age & 18 & 19 & 20 & 21 & 22\\
\end{Ttabular}

\bigskip\noindent
Which I want to look like
\bigskip

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{*3c}\toprule
\bfseries Name & \bfseries Sex & \bfseries Age\\\Midrule
Alice & Female & 18\\\midrule
Bob & Male & 19\\\midrule
Chuck & Male & 20\\\midrule
Dave & Male & 21\\\midrule
Eve & Female & 22\\\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Could please help me input more than 5 rows in the input when transposing the table? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have extra spaces in `\Ff = F` that need removal.  Should be `\Ff=F`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{collcell}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{environ}
%\usepackage{showframe}

\def\Midrule{\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]}

\newcounter{CurrentRow}% = column of transposed table
\newcounter{CurrentColumn}
\setcounter{CurrentColumn}{0}
\newtoggle{DoneWithFirstRow}

\newlength{\WidthAdjustment}
\newcommand*{\FirstColumn}[1]{%
    \IfEq{\arabic{CurrentColumn}}{0}{%
        % This is the start of the very first data entry in first row.
        \global\togglefalse{DoneWithFirstRow}%
        \setcounter{CurrentRow}{1}% initial value
    }{%
        % We have already completed a row. Now starting a new row.
        \global\toggletrue{DoneWithFirstRow}%
        \stepcounter{CurrentRow}%
    }%
    \setcounter{CurrentColumn}{0}%
    \NewData{#1}%
}
\newcommand*{\NewData}[1]{%
    \dtlexpandnewvalue%
    \stepcounter{CurrentColumn}%
    \iftoggle{DoneWithFirstRow}{%
        \dtlgetrow{TransposedTabularDB}{\arabic{CurrentColumn}}%
        \dtlappendentrytocurrentrow{\Alph{CurrentRow}}{#1}%
        \dtlrecombine%
    }{%
        \DTLnewrow{TransposedTabularDB}%
        \DTLnewdbentry{TransposedTabularDB}{\Alph{CurrentRow}}{#1}%
    }%
}%

\newcolumntype{F}{>{\collectcell\FirstColumn}c<{\endcollectcell}}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\collectcell\NewData}{c}<{\endcollectcell}}

%% No longer needed since we switched to NewEnviron
%% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12234/how-do-i-expand-a-macro-into-a-tabular-head
%\newcommand{\SaveColumnSpecificationAsZ}[1]{\newcolumntype{Z}{#1}}


\newtoggle{EncounteredDataRow}

\newsavebox{\TempBox}
\DTLnewdb{TransposedTabularDB}

\NewEnviron{Ttabular}[1]{%
    %\SaveColumnSpecificationAsZ{#1}%
    % Initialize in case of multiple uses
    \setcounter{CurrentColumn}{0}%
    \global\togglefalse{EncounteredDataRow}%
    \savebox{\TempBox}{%
        \begin{tabular}{FCCCCCC}% over speced tabular
            \BODY%
        \end{tabular}%
    }%
    \begin{tabular}{#1}\toprule%
    % This could be made smarter to detect number of columns
    \DTLforeach*{TransposedTabularDB}{\Aa=A, \Ba=B, \Ca=C, \Dd=D, \Ee=E, \Ff=F}{%
      \DTLiffirstrow{}{\\\midrule}%    
        \Aa & \Ba & \Ca & \Dd & \Ee & \Ff%
    }\\\bottomrule%
    \end{tabular}%
}%

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{Ttabular}{cccccc}
\bfseries Name & Alice & Bob & Chuck & Dave & Eve\\
\bfseries Sex & Female & Male & Male & Male & Female\\
\bfseries Age & 18 & 19 & 20 & 21 & 22\\
\bfseries Age & 18 & 19 & 20 & 21 & 22\\
\bfseries Age & 18 & 19 & 20 & 21 & 22\\
\bfseries Age & 18 & 19 & 20 & 21 & 22\\
\end{Ttabular}

\bigskip\noindent
Which I want to look like
\bigskip

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{*3c}\toprule
\bfseries Name & \bfseries Sex & \bfseries Age\\\Midrule
Alice & Female & 18\\\midrule
Bob & Male & 19\\\midrule
Chuck & Male & 20\\\midrule
Dave & Male & 21\\\midrule
Eve & Female & 22\\\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use the package **pgfplotstable** for this type of transformation, much simpler.

```
texdoc pgfplotstable
```

to read the manual (see page 63)

Short example below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{filecontents*}{example3.dat}
a b c d
0 1 2 3
4 5 6 7
8 9 10 11
12 13 14 15
16 17 18 19
20 21 22 23
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[string type]{example3.dat}

\pgfplotstabletranspose\loadedtable{example3.dat}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[string type]\loadedtable
\end{document}
```